# Why does my if statement work if I manually change the checked state, but not when I click the button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

New here, and a complete javascript newbie!

Question. I'm trying to make a piano, just as an exercise, my first real attempt at javascript(mixing some jQuery too).

But why does the audio not change when I click on my button? It works if I manually delete/add the checked state to the button in the html, but not 'live.'

Any ideas? I'm completely stumped, I guess it's either something to do with the audio being stored in memory or something, or I have to clear the audio, but I'm not sure. Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Here's the relevant bits of code. and a link:

https://testing.jconnorgraphics.co.uk/pianjo/

```
function test() {
var C = document.getElementById("myAudioC");
var C3 = document.getElementById("myAudioC3");



if (document.getElementById('checked').checked){

$('.C').click(function() {
                      delete ('myAudioC3');
                      C.play();
                      C.currentTime = 0;
                      C.delete()
                    }
        )
}

else {

$('.C').click(function() {

                        C3.play();
                        C3.currentTime = 0;
                        C3.delete()
                      }
        )
};
};

test();



<div class="switch2" >
      <label class="switch">

              <input id="checked" type="checkbox" checked>
              <span class="slider round"></span>
      </label>
      <p>Audio</p>
</div>


<div class="naturalkey C">
     <p>C</p>
</div>



<audio  id="myAudioC">
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/audio/piano/1 C.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<audio  id="myAudioC3">
    <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/audio/wavetable/2 C.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

Oh yeah, I'm creating it within Wordpress, hence the php bits, I don't think they are relevant to the problem though.

Comment: What's ".C"? Are you trying to select "myAudioC"?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that bit, edited now, .C is the class added to the div for the "Piano Key" that gets pressed and activates the sound. I'm trying to figure out how to change the sound based on a "switch"(bit like a change instrument button, I'll be switching all keys at once with that switch and possibly adding in more instruments, and trying to make the code work in loops, but one step at a time!).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Managed to get this working!

javascript

```
var C = document.getElementById("myAudioC");
var CC = document.getElementById("myAudioCC");

  function playAudioC() {
  var checked = document.getElementById("checked").checked;

  if ( checked == false) {
        C.play();
        C.currentTime = 0;
       }
       else
       {
      CC.play();
      CC.currentTime = 0;
      };

  };
```

html

```
  <audio  preload="auto" id="myAudioC">
  <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/audio/piano/1 C.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>

  <audio  preload="auto" id="myAudioCC">
  <source src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/audio/wavetable/2 C.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  </audio>

  <div onclick="playAudioC()" class="naturalkey">
      <p>C</p>
  </div>


<div class="switch2" >
  <label class="switch">

          <input id="checked" type="checkbox"  >
          <span class="slider round"></span>

  </label>
<p>Audio</p>
</div>
```

Next task is to turn all that in a loop, I've 12 keys to do, minimum, might take it further if I figure out the loop! Progress at least!

Answer (score 0):

This code will first set the onclick event of `.C` to be function a, then according to the `#checked` click event it will dynamically set `.C` onclick event.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  function a() {
      delete ('myAudioC3');
      C.play();
      C.currentTime = 0;
      C.delete()
    }

    function b() {
      C3.play();
      C3.currentTime = 0;
      C3.delete()
    }

    $('#checked').click(function(){
     let $this = $(this);

     if($this.attr('checked')) {
        $(".C").attr("onclick","a");  
        $this.attr('checked', false);
     } else {
       $(".C").attr("onclick","b");  
       $this.attr('checked',true)
     }
    });


    $(".C").attr("onclick","a");
});
```